# How to export the scheduled date to taskjuggler

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Having `(require 'ox-taskjuggler)` in my init.el and hitting `org-taskjuggler-export-process-and-open`
in *foo.org* renders the current date instead the expected scheduled date.

Content of *foo.org*

```
*** Foo                                                 :taskjuggler_project:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ORDERED:  t
    :scheduled: <2025-12-09 Tue>
    :END:
**** Bar
     :PROPERTIES:
     :Effort:   2w
     :END:
**** Acme
     :PROPERTIES:
     :Effort:   2w
     :END:
```

results in

[image: pic]

https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/taskjuggler/ox-taskjuggler.html

Comment: Does it work if you put `SCHEDULED: <2026-12-09 Tue>` under the `Foo` headline, *outside* of the property drawer?

Comment: @NickD Yes. That's the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `SCHEDULED` is a [special property](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) that should *not* go into a properties drawer: just like `DEADLINE`, it has to come right after the headline and before the properties drawer. That's where Org mode is looking for `SCHEDULED` or `DEADLINE` information.

So the Org mode file should look like this:

```org
*** Foo                                                 :taskjuggler_project:
    SCHEDULED: <2025-12-09 Tue>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ORDERED:  t
    :END:
**** Bar
     :PROPERTIES:
     :Effort:   2w
     :END:
**** Acme
     :PROPERTIES:
     :Effort:   2w
     :END:
```

`M-x org-lint` should flag problems like this and produce a useful report.